# angular4: innerHTML does not display "text-align: center"

Tags: html, angular, froala

I'm using [Froala](https://github.com/froala/angular-froala-wysiwyg) editor within my `Angular4` project
and I want to display what the user write inside the editor in another `<p>` tag.
The binding works perfectly fine :
in **my-component.html**:

```
<div [froalaEditor] [(froalaModel)]="froalaContent">Hello, Froala!</div>
<br>
<!-- here I display the editor content -->
{{froalaContent}} 
<br>
<!-- and here I convert the variable into html view -->
<p [innerHTML]="froalaContent"></p>
```

So this the display result:
[image]
But as you can see the tag `<p>` contains a css attribute `text-align:center;` but in the blow line the text is not centered and this is what I found in ChromeDevTools:
[image]

There is no `text-align: center;` attribute !!
Can someone explain this behaviour ? and thanx in advance.

Comment: You should take a look at Angular sanitizer for html written in a user input

Comment: @NoémiSalaün thanks for your reply, but where can I find this ?

Comment: I don't know if it will solve this particular problem, but look  https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: @NoémiSalaün Thanks man it worked :), add an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) to tell Angular that it is safe to keep the style set in the user input

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but this maybe help you...
The workaround is to use this:
  text-align: -moz-center;
instead of 
  text-align: center;

Comment: I can't because I'm getting the css attribute from froala, it's what the user write. so it's dynamic result